# classification for binary data in R

Tags: r, pca

Goodmorning everyone,

I'm working on a dataset of binary data ("yes","no"), and I am not sure of which is the right classification metric to apply for this case. I would like to get a comparison between two groups for several binary variables and know if their difference is statistically significant.

my data looks like that:

```
group<-c("ak","no-ak","ak","ak","no-ak","no-ak","no-ak")
autoimmunity<-c("no","yes","no","no","yes","yes","no")
smook<-c("yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","no")
lactose_int<-c("yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes")
coeliac_dis<-c("no","no","no","yes","no","yes","yes")
df<-data.frame(group,autoimmunity,smook,lactose_int,coeliac_dis)
> df
  group autoimmunity smook lactose_int coeliac_dis
1    ak           no   yes         yes          no
2 no-ak          yes   yes          no          no
3    ak           no   yes          no          no
4    ak           no    no         yes         yes
5 no-ak          yes   yes         yes          no
6 no-ak          yes    no         yes         yes
7 no-al           no    no         yes         yes
```

and I used at the moment MCA from FactoMineR in R

```
res.mca <- MCA(df, graph = FALSE)

fviz_mca_ind(res.mca, 
             label = "none", # hide individual labels
             habillage = "group", # color by groups 
             palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),
             addEllipses = TRUE, ellipse.type = "confidence",
             ggtheme = theme_minimal())
```

and I can get a plot but not a significativity for example comparing the two centroids. Does anyone can help me please?
thanks a lot
Andrea

Comment: Can you show an example of what you get and what you hope to get? It's hard to understand your problem from what you've written so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your data to numeric, for example, where one class equals `1` and the other `0`. This can be accomplished using `ifelse` in R.